# Getting yticks when using log scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting, visualization

I'm creating a colorplot with a logarithm scale (base 2) and trying to get the yticks from the colorbar to use somewhere else. However, what is shown in the plot is different from what is obtained from `get_yticks()`: the figure displays `[1,2,4,8,16]`, while the method gives me `[ 0.5  1.   2.   4.   8.  16.  32. ]`. Am I doing something wrong? Should I ignore the first and last entry (for some reason) in general?

The example code looks like this:

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure 
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter


x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
z = [[1, 1, 1, 1], [8, 8, 8, 8], [2, 2, 2, 2], [16, 16, 16, 16]]

# Creating figure and axis
fig = Figure(figsize=(4.0, 4.0))
ax = fig.subplots(1, 1)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.20, right=0.80, bottom=0.070,top=0.92)

# Plotting and getting colorbar
cbar = ax.pcolor(x, y, z, cmap='turbo', norm=LogNorm(1, 16))

# Getting axis extent
bbox = ax.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.transFigure.inverted())
# Creating axis for colorbar
cax = fig.add_axes([1.05*bbox.x1, bbox.y0, 0.1*(bbox.x1-bbox.x0), (bbox.y1-bbox.y0)])

# Adding colorbar
fig.colorbar(cbar, cax=cax)
# Setting logarithm scale without decimals
cax.set_yscale('log', base=2)
formatter = FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:.0f}'.format(y))
cax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

# Getting ticks
print(cax.get_yticks())  # Output: [ 0.5  1.   2.   4.   8.  16.  32. ]

fig.savefig('log_test.pdf')
```

Which produces this figure:
[image: Plot in logarithmic scale, base 2]

**Edit:** I have noticed that even in a simple plot using log scale, the returned ticks from `get_yticks()` are "wrong". Here is an example:

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure 
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

fig = Figure(figsize=(4.0, 4.0))
ax = fig.subplots(1, 1)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.20, right=0.80, bottom=0.070,top=0.92)

ax.plot(x, y)

ax.set_yscale('log', base=2)
formatter = FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:.0f}'.format(y))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

print(ax.get_yticks()) # Output: [0.125 0.25  0.5   1.    2.    4.    8.   ]

fig.savefig('log_test.pdf')
```

The figure looks like:

[image: Simple plot with log scale]

However, in this case the returned value is `[0.125 0.25  0.5   1.    2.    4.    8.   ]`, which shows that I can't even use the workaround of skipping the first and last values.

Comment: See [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html).

Comment: I don't know how this can help. Also, it doesn't seem connected to the colorbar itself (check the updated question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm looking for a better solution - as I still don't understand the return values of `get_yticks()`, I found a solution to check if the ticks are inside the ylim range:

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

fig = Figure(figsize=(4.0, 4.0))
ax = fig.subplots(1, 1)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.20, right=0.80, bottom=0.070, top=0.92)

ax.plot(x, y)

ax.set_yscale('log', base=2)
formatter = FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:.0f}'.format(y))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

yticks = ax.get_yticks()
print(yticks)  # Output with extra ticks: [0.125 0.25  0.5   1.    2.    4.    8.   ]

ylim = ax.get_ylim()
print("ylim", ylim) # Output: ylim (0.4665164957684037, 2.1435469250725863)

print([tick for tick in yticks if ylim[0] <= tick <= ylim[1]]) # Desired output: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]


fig.savefig('log_test.pdf')
```

This should remove all the unwanted ticks.